Access the output variable of a job, whose name is dynamically determine in azure pipeline in the same job
I am creating a template to download artifacts from another pipeline. I plan to use this template multiple times in the same job, e.g. 2 artifacts are required. For each artifact I download i want to print the "build" information associated with it.
  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    name: Download${{parameters.ArtifactName}}
    inputs:
      buildType: 'specific'
      project: 'myproject'
      definition: '${{parameters.PipelineRootName}}-${{parameters.ArtifactName}}-Build'
      specificBuildWithTriggering:  false
      buildVersionToDownload: 'latestFromBranch'
      branchName: 'refs/heads/release/${{parameters.ReleaseBranch}}'
      artifactName: ${{ parameters.ArtifactName }}
      targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\${{parameters.ArtifactName}}'
  - task: Powershell@2
    displayName: '${{parameters.ArtifactName}} Artifact Version Print'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        ### this line is the problem!! ###
        $BuildNumber = '$[ variables['${{parameters.ArtifactName}}.BuildNumber']]'
        Write-Host "${{parameters.ArtifactName}}.BuildNumber=$BuildNumber"

        $headers = @{
          Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
        }
        $uri="https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_apis/build/builds/$($BuildNumber)?api-version=7.0"
        $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method get -Headers $Headers -ContentType "application/json" 
        $result | select id, sourceBranch, sourceVersion, buildNumber, status, result, startTime, finishTime, reason, tags | convertTo-Json
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)

The challenge is retrieving the output variable of the "download" task. Since all artifacts are required in the same job, i can't split this into a different job. I used to have the name as simply "DownloadArtifact" and then i could get the build number by using $(DownloadArtifact.BuildNumber). However if i use the template twice i get a duplicate task name error. I can't find a syntax that works for obtaining the build number for the appropriate job. I've reviewed several SO examples, but so far have not had any luck finding a similar question and the usual workarounds don't help this situation.
Example Error:
char:31
+ $BuildNumber = '$[ variables['commonScripts.BuildNumber']]'
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'commonScripts.BuildNumber']]'' in expression or statement.


The output variable will be added to the environment variable. The cause of the issue is that the format of the nested variable has some issue. You can directly use the following format: $BuildNumber = '$(Download${{parameters.ArtifactName}}.BuildNumber)' it will be more easier to use the nested variable. For more info, you can refer to my answer below.

From your YAML sample, you are using the nested variable in Pipeline.
I can reproduce the same issue when using the format:
 '$[ variables['${{parameters.ArtifactName}}.BuildNumber']]'


I suggest that you can use the following format to use the nested variable in Pipeline:
$BuildNumber = '$(Download${{parameters.ArtifactName}}.BuildNumber)'

For example:
steps:
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  name: Download${{parameters.ArtifactName}}
  inputs:
    ....

- task: Powershell@2
  displayName: '${{parameters.ArtifactName}} Artifact Version Print'
  inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        $BuildNumber = '$(Download${{parameters.ArtifactName}}.BuildNumber)'
        Write-Host "${{parameters.ArtifactName}}.BuildNumber=$BuildNumber"

The output variable name of the download pipeline artifacts task: $(DownloadcommonScripts.BuildNumber)
Result:


I will give this a try, I thought i tried this in one of the many combinations i tried.

@Justin From your yaml code in question, it seems that you are missing the Download prefix in variable name.  for example: Download${{parameters.ArtifactName}}.BuildNumber Please try the sample in my answer and check if it can work. Feel free to let me know if you have any further questions.

Sorry for the late reply, this did fix my problem. Thanks!

In the process of writing this question, i stumbled on a solution. The job output variables are written to the environment variable, so we can actually access them this way instead.
$DownloadJobName = 'Download${{parameters.ArtifactName}}'
$BuildNumber = get-childitem env: | where name -eq "$DownloadJobName`_BuildNumber" | select -ExpandProperty Value
Write-Host "$DownloadJobName.BuildNumber=$BuildNumber"

The key thing is you do have to handle how characters are escaped, for example "." becomes "_", but this is pretty trivial.
